# Space between navigationbar and WKWebview IOS Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

[image]
[image]

Hi I am using NavigationBar with search but in when i click on button hiding navigation search and showing webview but it is showing space between both.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
 } else {
    mainTableView.tableHeaderView = nil
 }
```

I am using above code to hide the searchbar it is hiding but the space of the navigation bar is not removing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
```

> i think you are hiding only searchbar so, you may have to hide
>   navigation bar too so try above code

Comment: Yes I need to Hide Only searchbar.

Comment: @SrinivasCh have u tried  self.navigationItem.searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout, this behaviour is due to safe area layout guides. For device with notch, top constraint calculates distance from Safe Area(starting from notch).
To solve this, go to storyboard -> select WebView -> select top constraint. You will see few options related to constraint on Size inspector. Change Second Item to SuperView instead of Safe Area.

[image: screenshot of size inspector]

Comment: i have created webview programatically like this way.


        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        wkWebView.isHidden = true
        wkWebView.configuration.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true
        self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)